# ayuda con la función del webview

Tags: android, webview

### tengo un problema, tengo tres botones ylas url las quiero poner en una sola frame para simplificar pero cuando abro me sale me sale la direccion del otro boton...

```js
public class seccion extends Fragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_seccion_ofertas,container,false);
        Button btnofer1=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Promouno);
        Button btnofer2=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Promodos);
        Button btnofer3=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Promotres);
        btnofer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction framofe= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                framofe.replace(R.id.framelo,new Pruebaframe());
                framofe.commit();
            }
        });
        btnofer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction framofe= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                framofe.replace(R.id.framelo,new Pruebaframe());
                framofe.commit();
            }
        });
        btnofer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction framofe= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                framofe.replace(R.id.framelo,new Pruebaframe());
                framofe.commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

### **también puse esto... pero no se si esta bien**

```
public class Pruebaframe extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pruebaframe,container,false);

        WebView webfr1=view.findViewById(R.id.webofe1);
        WebView webfr2=view.findViewById(R.id.webofe2);
        WebView webfr3=view.findViewById(R.id.webofe3);

        webfr1.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        webfr2.loadUrl("https://es-la.facebook.com/");
        webfr3.loadUrl("https://www.instagram.com/?hl=es-la");

        return view;




    }
}
```

Comment: Solo deseas ver un WebView con la url relacionada al boton que realizaste clic? para esto no necesitas crear 3 WebView, puedes usar el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero solo tener un `WebView` el cual al recibir un valor al realizar la transaccion determine que url cargara.

Para esto debes modificar un poco tu clase que extiende de Fragment agregando un metodo el cual reciba este valor:

```
public class Pruebaframe extends Fragment {

  private int option;

  public static Pruebaframe newInstance (int option) {
     Pruebaframe fragment = new Pruebaframe()

     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putInt("option", option);
     fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
  }


  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pruebaframe,container,false);

      WebView webfr1=view.findViewById(R.id.webofe1);


    switch(option){
       case 0: {
           webfr1.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
       }
       case 1: {
           webfr1.loadUrl("https://es-la.facebook.com/");
       }
       case 2: {
           webfr1.loadUrl("https://www.instagram.com/?hl=es-la");
       } 
    }


    return view;



  }
```

}

La clase que carga el `Fragment` Pruebaframe también debe ser modificada para enviar el valor que determine el url a cargar:

```
 public class seccion extends Fragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_seccion_ofertas,container,false);
        Button btnofer1=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Promouno);
        Button btnofer2=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Promodos);
        Button btnofer3=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Promotres);

       Fragment fragment = null;

        btnofer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction framofe= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                //instancia Fragmen Pruebaframe con valor 0. 
                fragment = Pruebaframe.newInstance(0);

                framofe.replace(R.id.framelo, fragment /*new Pruebaframe()*/);
                framofe.commit();
            }
        });
        btnofer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction framofe= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                //instancia Fragmen Pruebaframe con valor 1. 
                fragment = Pruebaframe.newInstance(1);

                framofe.replace(R.id.framelo, fragment /*new Pruebaframe()*/);
                framofe.commit();
            }
        });
        btnofer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction framofe= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                //instancia Fragmen Pruebaframe con valor 2. 
                fragment = Pruebaframe.newInstance(2);

                framofe.replace(R.id.framelo, fragment /*new Pruebaframe()*/);
                framofe.commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
      }
   }
```